# Why are my JavaFX buttons unevenly spaced?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX, trying to build a GUI program that displays a bill for a table at a restaurant when you click on that table. The spacing is off between the table buttons and I'm not sure why.

[image]

The GUI class for my program:

```
package restaurantBillingProgram;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;

public class BillingGUI extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Create grid pane
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        pane.setHgap(5);
        pane.setVgap(5);

        // Label
        pane.add(new Label("Generate bill"), 1, 0);

        // Buttons
        Button btT1 = new Button("Table 1");
        pane.add(btT1, 0, 1);
        btT1.setOnAction(e - > Billing.generateT1());

        Button btT2 = new Button("Table 2");
        pane.add(btT2, 1, 1);
        btT2.setOnAction(e - > Billing.generateT2());

        Button btT3 = new Button("Table 3");
        pane.add(btT3, 2, 1);
        btT3.setOnAction(e - > Billing.generateT3());

        // Create scene and place in stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 250, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Restaurant Billing Program");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // Main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  The question included a [mcve] and enough info to be easily answered.  You could have studied the Javadoc more, but for a beginner there's an awful lot to assimilate.

Comment: Side note: When you want to add Table 4 you'll have to modify the source code.  Your current design is unmaintainable in general, but that's a much bigger and different topic :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Javadoc:

- Row/Column Sizing

  By default, rows and columns will be sized to fit their content; a column will be wide enough to accommodate the widest child, ...

The label in row 0 column 1 forces that column to be wider.

You probably want the label to be centered and span *all 3 columns*.

Answer (score 5):

While doing you layout, use `pane.setGridLinesVisible(true)`. This should only be used during debugging. It can be very useful for situations like your current situation. As @Jim Garrison pointed out, your `Label` is causing the issue:

Issue:

[image]

One way to fix this is to let the `Label` span all columns and center the `Label's` text.

Fix:

[image]

Key Code:

```
label.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
pane.add(label, 0, 0, 3, 1);// Look at the following link to see how this add method works. https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html#add(javafx.scene.Node,int,int,int,int)
```

Full Code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;

public class BillingGUI extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Create grid pane
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        pane.setHgap(5);
        pane.setVgap(5);
        pane.setGridLinesVisible(true);//Use for debugging only!!!!

        // Label
        Label label = new Label("Generate bill");
        label.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        pane.add(label, 0, 0, 3, 1);

        // Buttons
        Button btT1 = new Button("Table 1");
        pane.add(btT1, 0, 1);
       

        Button btT2 = new Button("Table 2");
        pane.add(btT2, 1, 1);
       

        Button btT3 = new Button("Table 3");
        pane.add(btT3, 2, 1);
       

        // Create scene and place in stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 250, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Restaurant Billing Program");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // Main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```